# Microsoft VS c++ 2010 list iterator error

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator

i'm having a list iterator not incrementable problem
i have a adjacency matrix "adj(2d vectors)" + i have a char vector in name color and i have a int glist
i'm having a problem with the following function

```
 for(list<int>::iterator it = glist.begin(); it != glist.end(); it++)
    {
        int x =0;
    for(int i=0;i<adj.at(*it).size();i++){
        if(color.at(adj.at(*it).at(i)) == 'w')
         x++;
    }
        if(x == 0)
        {
            it = glist.erase(it);
        }
    }
```

what i want from this function is to test if the neghbors of each elemnt in glist hase neighbors with white color (i.e the color of the neighbor in the color vector == "w" if it doesn't then deltet the element from the glist
but when i compile an error of list iterator not incrementable shows up 
any help will be appreciated

Comment: if any one wants me to post the whole code just tell me and i'll post it

Comment: sorry if my question is not well formed I'll try to improve it the next time

Answer (score 1):

Your logic skips an item of the list when you erase an item.

Say you have:

```
1 5 15 222
```

in your list. Let's say you end deleting `5` from the list. The lines:

```
if(x == 0)
{
    it = glist.erase(it);
}
```

will make `it` point to `15`. And you do `++it` in the `for` line, which makes `it` point to `222`. That means you skipped processing `15`.

If you end up deleting `222`, the lines:

```
if(x == 0)
{
    it = glist.erase(it);
}
```

will make `it` point to `glist.end()`. When you do `++it` on that, you will see undefined behavior.

Change your logic to update `it` by using:

```
if(x == 0)
{
    it = glist.erase(it);
}
else
{
    ++it;
}
```

and change the `for` line to:

```
for(list<int>::iterator it = glist.begin(); it != glist.end(); /* it++ /*)
                                                               // ^^^^ Don't need.
```